# Can I store static files on nginx whith cloudbees?

Tags: caching, nginx, cloudbees, static-files

As far as I know, cloudbees is using nginx servers for routing the requests.

I am wondering if there is a way to drop my static files on nginx to make it serves my static files and save some load on my application server.

M.

Answer (score 0):

On runtime the file system is "ephermeral". You have more info about it [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/File+system+access).

You should use an external service like Amazon S3. The [Amazon S3 ClickStart](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart) explains how to use this service from CloudBees.

You can also use other services like Dropbox or Google Drive.